# How can I have the background colour of UIPageControl change along with the page swipe?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a tutorial screen when my app is first launched

I'd like to have the background colour change as the user swipes from page to page. I have this working, basically, but the page control colour is not changing until the swipe transition has completed.

[image: UIPageViewController scrolling with background colour change]

*(In this screen shot, I'm scrolling mid-way between page 0 and page 1 to show the background colour change)*

How can I have the background colour change WITH the page scroll?

Here's the code from my main view controller - it's in Rubymotion but you should be able to follow it:

```
# ...

def page_control
  page_controller.view.pageControl
end

COLORS = [UIColor.greenColor, UIColor.blueColor, UIColor.orangeColor]

def pageViewController(page_view_controller, didFinishAnimating: finished, previousViewControllers: previous_view_controllers, transitionCompleted: completed)   
   background_color = COLORS[page_control.currentPage % COLORS.size]
   page_control.backgroundColor = background_color
end

# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just set UIPageControl's backgroundColor to clearColor?

Comment: I tried that - it inherits the background colour from the parent controller's view instead. The page views don't overlap the page control

Comment: why not overlap the page views to the entire height of the controller's view then?  or did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I ended up implementing my own `UIPageControl`.  Create a new view in your main view controller, and then add both the `UIPageViewController` view and the `UIPageControl` as subviews, with the frames set so the page control appears at the bottom (or wherever you prefer) of the pageViewController view.

**EDIT**
Because the `UIPageViewController` is being displayed as a subview of another controller, you have to call (from the main view controller) `[self addChildViewController:pageViewController]` immediately before you add it as a subview.  And afterwards call `[pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]`.  This ensures that touch events etc are passed from the main view controller to the page view controller. See the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12).
**END EDIT**

Set the page control's background colour to `clearColor` and the transition from one page to the next will happen "behind" the page control.  You can then update the page control (`currentPage` and, if necessary, `numberOfPages`) in the `pageViewController didFinishAnimating` delegate function.  If you want to be able to tap the page control to switch pages, add a suitable target/action method when you create it, and use the `UIPageViewController`'s `setViewControllers:animated:` method to trigger the transition.

To ensure that the `UIPageViewController` does not also present a page control, remove your implementations of `presentationCountForPageViewController:` and `presentationIndexForPageViewController:`.

Comment: That sounds promising - let me try it and report back :)

Comment: @bodacious I realised there's another step I should have mentioned regarding adding one view controller as a subview of another - though you may already be aware.  I'll edit my answer.